# How to build the .ipa with iOS 7 support in Xcode 11.2.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode11

Recently I updated the Xcode to version 11.2.1 and imported an already developed iOS application with `Minimum Deployment target` as **7**. But when i opened the project in Xcode 11 I can find the **Minimum Deployment target** as 8.

1. So how can I extend the support for this application for iOS 7 too
   using Xcode 11? If yes, then how?
2. Is it possible to download the iOS 7 simulator in
   Xcode 11 and test it?
3. Is there any official document which says
   the Xcode 11 is not providing support for iOS 7 devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i extend the support for this application for iOS 7 too using Xcode 11? if Yes then how?

Yes, just type the number into the input.

> Is it possible to download the iOS 7 simulator in Xcode 11 and test it?

Never try for long time, but I think it's impossible. But you can test with real device. (You need to copy 7.x directory from old Xcode `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` to the this one.)

> Is there any official document which says the Xcode 11 is not providing support for iOS 7 devices?

Not sure.

Comment: Thanks ... So are you sure ...  "Yes, just type the number into the input." - it will be supporting the iOS 7 and above devices?

Comment: Another place need to check is TARGETS.
After type 7.0 in Deployment target, then you can select Target to iOS 7.0.
You can verify by open file Yourproject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj and find "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" and "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"